# Mysterious no-match in regular expression

Tags: regex, matlab

Imagine I have a cell array with two filenames:

```
filenames{1,1} = 'SMCSx0noSat48VTFeLeakTrace.txt';
filenames{2,1} = 'SMCSx0NoSat48VTrace.txt';
```

I want to get the filename which starts with `'SMCSx0'` and contains the filterword `'NoSat48VTrace'`:

```
%// case 1
expression = 'SMCSx0';
filterword = 'NoSat48VTrace';
regs = regexp(filenames, ['^' expression '.*\' filterword '.*\.txt$'])
mask = ~cellfun(@isempty,regs);
file = filenames(mask)
```

it works, I get:

```
file = 

    'SMCSx0NoSat48VTrace.txt'
```

But for whatever reason does the change of the filterword to `'noSat48VTFeLeakTrace'` doesn't get me the other file?

```
%// case 2
expression = 'SMCSx0';
filterword = 'noSat48VTFeLeakTrace';
regs = regexp(filenames, ['^' expression '.*\' filterword '.*\.txt$'])
mask = ~cellfun(@isempty,regs);
file = filenames(mask)
```

which is absolutely the same as before, but

```
file = 

   Empty cell array: 0-by-1
```

I'm actually use these lines in a function for months, without problems. But now I added some files to my folder which are not found, though their names are similar to before. Any hints?

---

It is actually supposed to work without including `Trace` into the filterword, which it does for the first case, that's why I put `.*\` into the regex.

```
%// case 1
expression = 'SMCSx0';
filterword = 'NoSat48V';
... works
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'^' expression '.*\'
```

The `\` near the end makes it that `\n` is interpreted as a new-line character:

```
SMCSx0.*\noSat48VTFeLeakTrace.*\.txt$
```

This worked fine with the other filterword because `NoSat48VTrace` has an upper case `N` and `\N` is interpreted as simply `N`.

Get rid of the `\`, you don't need it.

Comment: Thank you, makes actually sense. I have a hundred files with a capital N there, but just made the little typo this week. Incredible, how such a minor change can make everything crash ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra backslash in there:

```
regs = regexp(filenames, ['^' expression '.*\' filterword '.*\.txt$'])
                                           ^^^
                                           |||
```

remove it and it should give the expected result.

Comment: thanks! I accepted the other answer, as it was posted at the same time but is more complete.